# unable to get number from user and pass it as a parameter in javascript slice method

Tags: javascript, html, slice

I'm making a small application which shows how strings are manipulated in javascript by using different methods ,I'm trying to get number as a input and pass that number as parameter to slice the string but it is not working because i am unable to get number from user . i tried to print the number in the console but it is showing an empty line

here is my that might help you understand where i'm making a mistake
**HTML Code**

```
<input type="number" placeholder="number" class="number1">
<input type="number" placeholder="number" class="number2">
<button class="sliced">slice</button>
<h1 id="displaytext"></h1>
```

**Javascript code**

```
let message = document.querySelector("#displaytext")
let slicedButton = document.querySelector(".sliced")
let number1 = document.querySelector(".number1").value 
let number2 =document.querySelector(".number2").value
slicedButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    console.log(number1,number2)
    message.innerHTML = userInput.value.slice(number1, number2)
})
```

Comment: Could you showcase example what type of slice you want and what does variable `userInput` refer to in the text. For example, say, you want to slice string `14555` from number1 by number2 input  which is `2` to get such and such result. Because from the current function and description, it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: userInput is input field to get string from user and i have saved it as a varible using dom . thank for reading my question , can i show you my code i found the answer ,it might help you to understand what the problem was and how i solved because i'm new to stack-overflow i'm unable to exactly tell what the problem is

Comment: `value`s read to variables are just strings, they're not connected to the actual value of the inputs. You've to read the values from the inputs in the listener.

Comment: @Teemu Okay I get it, your problem is you don't get `number1` and `number2` values in the listener, right?

Comment: @Teemu sorry, wrong addressing. @Path man you just should get the elements inside the event listener. outside the dom may not be loaded yet, that's why they're null. Or put all of your code inside `load` event listener.

Comment: yes this method also worked for me but i'm not passing the value as soon the page loads but after i press the slice button and i want to use this number also for other methods like substr(), charAt() and  substring(). my code would look complete chaos if i declare new varible everytime for new button

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the values inside the call back function.

```
let message = document.querySelector("#displaytext")
let slicedButton = document.querySelector(".sliced")

slicedButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
let number1 = document.querySelector(".number1").value 
let number2 =document.querySelector(".number2").value
    console.log(number1,number2)
    //message.innerHTML = userInput.value.slice(number1, number2)
})
```

Comment: Actually i found the answer ,rather than saving the direct let number1 = document.querySelector(".number1").value  in variable,i saved it without .value and when giving parameter to slice method i passed slice(number1.value, number2.value)

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript code executes as soon as your page loads, which is why number1 and number2 get assigned "" immediately. Move the logic that gets the input value into the listener, to receive the latest value:

```
let message = document.querySelector("#displaytext")
let slicedButton = document.querySelector(".sliced")
slicedButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
let number1 = document.querySelector(".number1").value 
let number2 =document.querySelector(".number2").value
    console.log(number1,number2)
    message.innerHTML = userInput.value.slice(number1, number2)
})
```

However this still throws as uerInput is undefined